# the usage of aggregate(0, lambda,lambda) in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

There is a pyspark code segment

```
seqOp = (lambda x,y: x+y)
sum_temp = df.rdd.map(lambda x: len(x.timestamp)).aggregate(0, seqOp, seqOp)
```

The output of sum_temp is a numerical value. But I am not clear how does the      `aggregate(0, seqOp, seqOp)`  work. It seems to me that normally, the `aggregate` just use a single function form like `"avg"`

Moreover, `df.rdd.map(lambda x: len(x.timestamp))` is of type     `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD`. How can we get its contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.aggregate), the aggregation process:

1. Starts from the first argument as the zero-value (0),
2. Then each partition of the RDD is aggregated using the second argument, and
3. Finally the aggregated partitions are combined into the final result using the third argument. Here, you sum up each partition, and then you sum up the sums from each partition into the final result.

You might have confused this aggregate with the aggregate method of dataframes. RDDs are lower-level objects and you cannot use dataframe aggregation methods here, such as avg/mean/etc.

To get the contents of the RDD, you can do `rdd.take(1)` to check a random element, or use `rdd.collect()` to check the whole RDD (mind that this will collect all data onto the driver and could cause memory errors if the RDD is huge).

Comment: thank you for the answer, after reading the docs, I am not very clear the neural zero value, could you clarify more?

Comment: that's the value which forms the beginning of the aggregation process

Comment: So it functions as initial value for operation like sum over an array.